# CakePHP installation to work with 2 different URLs

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I have a cakephp 2.3.5 installation with this structure:

/root
../CakePHP
..../Cake_core_files
..../apps
....../my-app
......../app
........../Config, /Controller, /View, etc
..../public_html
....../my-app-webroot
......../css, /img, etc

Now I would like this same app to be able be accessed with 2 different domains:

- mydomain1.com: points to **public_html**, so the website is accessed with *http://mydomain1.com/myapp-webroot*
- mydomain2.com: points to **public_html/my-app-webroot**, so the website is accesed with *http://mydomain2.com*

Using the default CakePHP's **htaccess** this setup works fine for *mydomain2*, but for *mydomain1* it only works for the initial page, any other link inside the website returns a not found error.

For example, with *mydomain1*, accessing *mydomain1.com/my-app-webroot* shows the initial page fine, but if I click on a link like *mydomain1.com/my-app-webroot/mycontroller/somepage* then it can't find it. However, if I go to *mydomain2.com/mycontroller/somepage* then it works fine.

Note: in the routes file I have the '/' connected with 'mycontroller/index'.

Any ideas on how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create rewrite rules in the .htaccess in your hosting packages, based on the fact that you told that the domains are pointing to your hosting. The second domain, is that an add-on or parked one? If one domain is an add-on domain this might be your problem. Add-on domains works independently! Well at least in our hosting servers. Hope that helps to find your problem.

Comment: in the end it was a matter of removing the "RewriteBase /" line from the htaccess file in the webroot

Comment: Yip that's the reason, glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to pointing all the domains to the same website. One part involves changing the settings at your domain name registrar. The other part requires you to get your web host to add those additional domain names to your account. It probably doesn't matter which part you do first (unless your web host is fussy), but you'll need to get both done.

For more Detail you can go to this website
http://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/point-multiple-domains-one-website.shtml

Comment: I have that part done already, pointing the domains to where they're supposed to it's not a problem, the problem comes when navigatiing the website (see my explanation above).